# Reading a 0 - 1V Signal - Weird cable

Tags: voltage, analog, raspberry-pi, cables, rca

I am trying to read a -0.1 - 1 Volt signal using a Raspberry Pi for data analysis and a Gertboard for the ADC and actual voltage reading.

The signal comes from a scientific equipment which has an RCA-Output. A photo of the cable that came with the equipment is below[image]

The RCA male is connected to the equipment and ends in two (+ and -) spaded tongue terminals (Japanese E JST 1.25-S3). I want to connect these two ends to my Gertboard.

What would be the adequate way to do this?

I have thought about creating two cables, each with an spaded tongued end and a "normal" end which can go into the gertboard. I would then join each pair of tongued terminals with a screw. Is this feasible or am I missing something?

Comment: For who were wondering, like me, what a Gertboard is: [Gertboard is an IO expansion board for the Raspberry Pi](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chop the spades off and solder the wires to a 0.1" pin socket and plug it into ADC1 or ADC2 on the Gertboard. If you don't want to destroy the cable that came with the equipment then go down to Radio-shack or Tandy (do they still exist) or Maplin (in the UK and maybe elsewhere) and buy a cheap RCA cable and butcher this to suit your needs.

Or buy an RCA to RCA cable and get one of these: -

[image]

[Source of RCA break out boards](http://www.gravitech.us/newrcabrbo.html)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. That makes a lot of sense, what do you think about a similar approach using this? http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/MjA5NzQ1OTk-/Unterhaltungselektronik/Steckverbinder/Cinch/Cinchkupplung_DAYCOM_A_CS_SK.html

Comment: Yes, that looks a neat way of doing it.

Comment: Awesome, will do that. I have one last doubt. I can see the cables which are connected to the spaded terminals. The diameter of the one on the (-) terminal is easily double as big as the one on the (+) terminal. Should I also use different thick cables for the sockets on the break-out board or RCA-adapter?

Comment: Just keep the wires the same and as short as possible.